# Ansible tasks cannot have sudo_user on a certain Vagrant box (bento)

Tags: vagrant, ansible, bento

The following task fails on a Vagrant box (ubuntu 12.04 chefless) http://opscode.github.io/bento/

```
  - name: ensure database is created
    postgresql_db: name={{dbname}}
    sudo_user: postgres
```

fd

```
failed: [192.168.78.8] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: Sorry, user vagrant is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo SUDO-SUCCESS-lalargtagydzinzenmftocwaiucrmxuk; /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-1392568385.89-150322815243790/postgresql_db' as postgres on cogol-dev.
```

Will I need to create my own box ?

=== content of /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    exempt_group=sudo
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your sudo permissions are on the vagrant box. On your vagrant box, run `grep vagrant /etc/sudoers` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I added the whole content of /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably being late here, but I encountered same error today and resolved it with

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

your `sudo` group missing this `ALL` in parentheses

Comment: Late for OP, but +1 as this is the solution for me, too (chef/Ubuntu 14 with vagrant).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you must also add `sudo: yes` below/above the `sudo_user` param.

Comment: I get the same error using `sudo_user`, even when I add `sudo: yes`